# diagram for client/server communication

Tags: uml, client-server, diagram

i am writing a client/server application. Now i want to do some basic diagrams about the communication, but I don`t know which kind UML-diagram i should choose. It should be really basic without going much into detail, only fundamental procedures.

The only diagram that comes to my mind is the sequence diagram, but i don`t think it is sutable for this purpose.

Am i forgetting a diagram? Or is none UML-diagram suitable for this?
What kind of diagram would you advise me to use?

Comment: why don't you think sequence diagram is suitable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends a bit on what you want to document:

- if it's message order, sequence diagrams are really the way to go
- if the focus is on who exchanges messages with whom (and maybe their roles in the communication), use [communication diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_diagram)
- if you want to describe what messages can be exchanged between client and server (i.e. the message API), use [component diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_diagram) to describe the general client/server interface and class diagrams to flesh out the message details of the interface.

Comment: But there is None to describe what and why sth is exchanged? I meam somenthing Which contains more Information about the Message then getsomething(argument)

Comment: @user1080014 Usually a message may be represented as an identifier to an object, and later, in a class diagram, the class or object is explained in detail

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with using Sequence Diagrams ?

```
..................................................
..+------------+......+------------+..............
..|  *:Client  |......|  *:Server  |..............
..+------+-----+......+------+-----+..............
.........|...................|....................
.......+-+-+...............+-+-+..................
.......|   |.doSomething().|   |..................
.......|   +==============>+   +==+..............
.......|   |...............|   |..|...............
.......|   |...<<return>>..|   |..|...............
.......|   +<--------------+   +<=+...............
.......|   |...............|   |..................
.......+-+-+...............+-+-+..................
.........|...................|....................
.........X...................X....................
..................................................
```

Seems to me that its ok to use these diagrams.

Cheers.

Comment: it's rather difficult to make a suggestion without knowing what you consider "too much detail" and what's "unclear". Could you elaborate a bit?